# How to simplify this logarithm?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I am looking at an example in my algorithms textbook, and I cannot seem to figure out how the following simplification occurred (my logarithm skills are a bit rusty):

From this:
$$\sqrt{n}c\sqrt{n}\lg\lg\sqrt{n}+n\le{cn\lg\lg n}$$

To this:
$$nc(\lg\lg n-\lg2)+n\le{cn\lg\lg n}$$

And finally to this:
$$-clg2+1\le{0}$$

I am mainly confused by the second step. I don't follow all the steps that lead to getting $\lg\lg n - \lg2$

Any help in clarifying this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

$$\log\left(\log n^{1/2}\right)=\log\left(\frac{1}{2}\log n\right)=\log\frac{1}{2}+\log\log n=-\log 2+\log\log n$$